# can an alert or notification call up a certain view when opening a app or bringing it out of suspension?

Tags: ios5, uilocalnotification

Say I have an app that sets reminders in the notification center:

`Friday @ 4pm Change car oil`

And when swiped or selected that notification will open or bring the app out of suspension.

Is it possible to make the notification trigger the app to show a certain view or will the app always just default to its main or suspended state screen?

Answer (score 0):

Your app can tell whether the local notification woke it up or started it, and then show a certain view based on that:

1. If the app was suspended and has is reactivated by the user selecting a local notification, `-application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` will be called, and `[application applicationState]` will be `UIApplicationStateInactive`.
2. If the app was not running before and has been started by the user selecting a local notification, the local notification will be passed in the options of `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` under the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`.